# can't install pptk in python

Tags: python, pip, pptk

I'm trying to install the pptk module in PyCharm for visualising 3D point clouds.

Initially I tried installing in PyCharm via File > Settings > Python Interpreter > Install > pptk

However, it couldn't be found and advised I use pip instead.

So on my command prompt I navigated to the folder containing Python 3.9 and tried `pip install pptk`

And I got the following error `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pptk (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for pptk`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or why no version can be found? Am I missing something obvious in the installation?

Comment: Your Python is probably on the wrong version. Try Python 3.6.

Comment: @thethiny thanks, I'll give that a try and update the post with my result

Comment: you were right @thethiny. Downloaded with Python 3.6, no issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the requirements by the `pptk` module, the minimum Python version required is 3.6. Judging by the fact that there's no distribution found for 3.9 I believe that it was missing a PyPi repo for it, therefore downgrading to Python 3.6 should fix the problem. Judging by your response to my comment, that did work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answer was wrong or it is simply outdated, but it doesn't support 3.6 as well.

I successfuly instaled it on Python 3.7. Just to save you the time - the latest version with installers - https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-379/